# Как быстро разбить видео на части по размеру через командную строку оптимальным образом?

Tags: cmd, ffmpeg, split

Хочу разбить видео на части по 2GB. Нашел большое количество прог, которые почти позволяют это делать:

- ffmpeg - эта программа позволяет получить 1 файл нужного размера командой `ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -fs 2000M "output.mp4"`, следующие части уже не получить. Вроде [тут](https://progi.pro/ispolzovanie-ffmpeg-dlya-razdeleniya-videofaylov-po-razmeru-5918277) описывается, что с помощью `ss` можно разбить, но я не понял как. Или `ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 01:00:00 -async 1 cut.mp4`, тут можно получить сколько угодно частей просто изменяя временной отрезок, но не отгадаешь его размер.
- boisoft splitter - можно разбить на части по размеру, но она это делает долго (около получаса) и она не поддерживает командную строку -> не автоматизировать разбиение.
- mp4box - `mp4box -splits 80000 filename.mp4` - вроде как должна разбивать, но по факту съедает столько оперативки сколько может и умирает видос не разбив

Как добиться быстрого разбиения без перекодирования по размеру через командную строку?

Comment: В ffmpeg есть фильтр [segment](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment), но к сожалению он делит не по размеру, а по времени. Но если битрейт постоянный, можно попытаться подгадать нужное время

Comment: @andreymal битрейт не одинаковый(

Comment: C какой точностью вы хотите вписаться в размер?

Comment: @gbg не больше 2000MB, не меньше 1700MB.

Answer (score 0):

Порезать на мелкие чанки, скажем, секунд по 100, потом чанки склеить до достижения нужной длины.

Если погрешность  важна, резать на более мелкие чанки.

Comment: Во-первых чем разбивать на части (так чтобы не перегружать систему).
Во-вторых, даже если разбить на файлы по 1 сек, они будут чуть чуть различаться (на байты), но если их всех потом соединить различие будет такое же, как просто по временным интервалам разбивать.